# node-mysql single value for multiple query parameters

Tags: mysql, node.js, prepared-statement

Currently, in node.js, if I want to search for a string in multiple columns in a MySQL table I have to do like this:

```
mysqlConnection.query(
    "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column_a LIKE ? OR column_b LIKE ? OR column_c LIKE ?",
    [searchString, searchString, searchString],
    callback
);
```

I want to be able to do it like this:

```
mysqlConnection.query(
    "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column_a LIKE ? OR column_b LIKE ? OR column_c LIKE ?", 
    searchString, callback
);
```

Or maybe even with named parameters:

```
mysqlConnection.query(
    "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column_a LIKE :searchString OR column_b LIKE :searchString OR column_c LIKE :searchString",
    {searchString: "needle"},
    callback
);
```

Is there a way I can do it?

Comment: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#custom-format

Comment: @robertklep Well, that's pretty much what I'm looking for... but I don't think I should be trusted to prepare the statement myself. I might end up poking holes in the security.

Comment: Well, the code that I linked to is provided by the developer of `mysql`, and AFAICS it's _exactly_ what you want :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can enable named parameter when creating your db pool connection.

```
const connection = mysql.createPool({
  ...yourConfig,
  namedPlaceholders: true,
});
```

edit: As @robertklep explained it only works on mysql2 npm package

Comment: To be clear: that will work with `mysql2`, not with `mysql`.